# Generating a signed JWT token with PowerShell to connect to Azure AD and SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, jwt, certificate

I have an Azure AD app registration that I use to connect to SharePoint using a certificate. I want to test api calls and for this I use PostMan. To test with a certificate in PostMan I need to use a client assertion.

How can I easily generate a JWT token from my PFX file?
I found this piece of PowerShell but can't get it to work. Neither in PS5 or PS7

```
$x509cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new($CertificatePath_Pfx, $CertPassWord)
$signingX509Certificate = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($CertificatePath_Pfx, $CertPassWord, 'Export')
$claims = new-object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String, Object]'
$claims['aud'] = $aud
$claims['iss' ] = $ClientId
$claims['sub'] = $ClientId
$claims['jti'] = [GUID]::NewGuid().ToString('D')
                
#$signingCredentials = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SigningCredentials]::new($x509cert)
$signingCredentials = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SigningCredentials($signingX509Certificate)
$securityTokenDescriptor = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor]::new()
$securityTokenDescriptor.Claims = $claims
$securityTokenDescriptor.SigningCredentials = $signingCredentials

$tokenHandler = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler]::new()
$clientAssertion = $tokenHandler.createToken($securityTokenDescriptor)
write-host $clientAssertion
```

I am getting the following error:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'PerTypeValues`1' threw an excep
tion."
At C:\temp\certs\GetClientAssertion.ps1:50 char:24
+ ... edentials = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509S ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

On this line:

```
$signingCredentials = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SigningCredentials($signingX509Certificate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is something related to my PowerShell version. I am using V5. When using the code in a .NET FrameWork console app I do get the token I need to generate a usable token.

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GetJwtToken
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ClientID = "****";
            string TenantID = "****";
            string CertPassWord = "password";
            string aud = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/****/oauth2/token";
            string CertificatePath_Pfx = "C:\\Temp\\Certs\\test.pfx";



            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(CertificatePath_Pfx, CertPassWord);
            var claims = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<String, Object>();
            claims["aud"] = aud;
            claims["iss"] = ClientID;
            claims["sub"] = ClientID;
            claims["jti"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");

            var signCred = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SigningCredentials(cert);
            var securityTokenDescriptor = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor();
            securityTokenDescriptor.Claims = claims;
            securityTokenDescriptor.SigningCredentials = signCred;

            Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler tokenHandler = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler();
            var clientAssertion = tokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
            Console.Write(clientAssertion);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Here is a working version in PowerShell. Only works in PS7. Manually add the dll's to the script folder:

```
$ClientID           = "***" # Application/Client id used for the cert name 
$TenantID      = "***" # tenant id is used for the cert name 
$CertPassWord       = "password" # Password used for creating the certificate
$aud                = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/token"
$CertificatePath_Pfx = "C:\Temp\Certs\test.pfx" # Path where the certificate is saved
 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\System.Memory.dll")


Function Get-ClientAssertion {
    $x509cert = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($CertificatePath_Pfx, $CertPassWord)
    $claims = new-object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String, Object]'
    $claims['aud'] = $aud
    $claims['iss' ] = $ClientId
    $claims['sub'] = $ClientId
    $claims['jti'] = [GUID]::NewGuid().ToString('D')
                    
    $signingCredentials = new-object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SigningCredentials($x509cert)
    $securityTokenDescriptor = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor]::new()
    $securityTokenDescriptor.Claims = $claims
    $securityTokenDescriptor.SigningCredentials = $signingCredentials 
    $tokenHandler = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler]::new()
    $clientAssertion = $tokenHandler.createToken($securityTokenDescriptor)
    write-host $clientAssertion
}  

$myvar = Get-ClientAssertion
```

This is a working version for PS 5.1

```
$ClientID           = "****" # Application/Client id used for the cert name 
$TenantID      = "****" # tenant id is used for the cert name 
$CertPassWord       = "password" # Password used for creating the certificate
$aud                = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/token"
$CertificatePath_Pfx = "C:\Temp\Certs\test.pfx" # Path where the certificate is saved
 
 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\System.Text.Json.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll")

<#
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\System.Security.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Temp\Certs\System.Memory.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("c:\temp\certs\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll")
#>


$OnAssemblyResolve = [System.ResolveEventHandler] {
    param($sender, $e)

    $searchFor = $null
    if ($e.Name -match "(.*?), .*") {
        $searchFor = $matches[1]
    }
    foreach ($a in [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
        $foundItem = $null
        if ($a.FullName -match "(.*?), .*") {
            $foundItem = $matches[1]
        }
    
        if ($foundItem -eq $searchFor) {
            return $a
        }
    }
    return $null
}

[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.add_AssemblyResolve($OnAssemblyResolve)

Function Get-ClientAssertion {
    $x509cert = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($CertificatePath_Pfx, $CertPassWord)
    $x509cert
    $claims = new-object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String, Object]'
    $claims['aud'] = $aud
    $claims['iss' ] = $ClientId
    $claims['sub'] = $ClientId
    $claims['jti'] = [GUID]::NewGuid().ToString('D')
                    
    $signingCredentials = new-object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SigningCredentials($x509cert)
    
    $securityTokenDescriptor = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor]::new()
    $securityTokenDescriptor.Claims = $claims
    $securityTokenDescriptor.SigningCredentials = $signingCredentials 
    $tokenHandler = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler]::new()
    $clientAssertion = $tokenHandler.createToken($securityTokenDescriptor)
    write-host $clientAssertion
    
}  

$myvar = Get-ClientAssertion
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to generate a token in PowerShell is to use [the PowerShell MSAL module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSAL.PS/4.2.1.3).

To install the module:

```
Install-Module MSAL.PS
```

Sample of code:

```
Import-Module MSAL.PS

$pfxPath = "C:\mycert.pfx"
$pfxPwd = "p@ssw0rd!"
$clientId = ""
$tenantId = ""

$clientCertificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($pfxPath, $pfxPwd)
$token = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientId -ClientCertificate $clientCertificate -TenantId $tenantId -ForceRefresh
$jwt = $token.accesstoken
```

Other sample with scope:

```
Import-Module MSAL.PS

$pfxPath = "C:\mycert.pfx"
$pfxPwd = "p@ssw0rd!"
$clientId = ""
$tenantId = ""
$scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"

$clientCertificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($pfxPath, $pfxPwd)
$token = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientId -ClientCertificate $clientCertificate -TenantId $tenantId -ForceRefresh -Scope $scope
$jwt = $token.accesstoken
```

To make HTTP request with this token, create a header like that:

```
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $jwt"
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json;odata=verbose"
}
```

But, if you want to connect to SharePoint, why not try the [PowerShell PnP module?](https://github.com/pnp/powershell)

```
Import-Module PowerShell.PnP

$pfxPath = "C:\mycert.pfx"
$pfxPwd = "p@ssw0rd!"
$clientId = ""
$siteUrl = "https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site"
$tenantName = "your-tenant.onmicrosoft.com"

Connect-PnPOnline -ClientId $clientId -CertificatePath $pfxPath -CertificatePassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $pfxPwd -Force) -Url $siteUrl -Tenant $tenantName
```

Comment: What do I pass as scope? I get errors that I need to pass a scope

Comment: I got scope working. But when copying token and use it in PostMan I get: ADSTS700222: AAD-issued tokens may not be used for federated identity flows.

Comment: I can however use the token to access the SharePoint api's

Comment: I edit my answer!

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. It took me in the direction I needed. The MSAL produces a bearer token that can be used in requests. I needed the client_assertion token from my certificate. I used a console app with same code as in my PS script. The console works. I think something related to PowerShell version and .NET FrameWork. With the assertion token I can generate my bearer token. And this is just what I needed.

Comment: Btw I am using PnP for almost everything. But for some questions I got form other developers in my organization I am making some examples with clean HTTP requests.